# C++: detect small line parallel in image

Tags: image-processing

I try to get small edge in image. I tried to use Local line binary pattern, sobel, and some other methods to get image, but cannot get the parallel lines in the image.

How can I find the lines?

[image]

Comment: Can you add the code that you are using? Easier to help that way. Also, you can try with different color spaces and channels before edge detection. Some features are prominent in other spaces/channels instead of just RGB

Comment: here is code i write, i try with sobel, canny but not good, i think LBP can use to extract edge with uniform pattern, but it not good, i try HLBP but HLBP detected big edge, not small edge i want: https://pastebin.com/cA2tp9kM

Comment: what exactly are you interested in? what's the purpose of this? do you need the lines or just their direction? freqency? which lines do you mean? please add an image that has graphical annotations

Comment: my purpose was try to find all line in this image, I try with LSD http://www.ipol.im/pub/art/2012/gjmr-lsd/ but result no good!